# How to determine correct scoping for Microservices

Tags: microservices

Hello fellow Software engineers,

I've been doing a lot of research on microservices these last few days and have come across a great deal of articles and videos explaining the concept, programming models and things alike.

Now I am tasked with designing a platform that offers microservices and I've run into a snag. I haven't found a good answer in the articles and videos I've come across. The problem I am facing is that when I am trying to scope my microservices, I have a feeling I am over-scoping things. Despite reading over-scoping isn't bad, I am afraid I have reached the point of creating nano-services.

Now I know nano-services on their own arn't the end of the world. But in a perfect world, you'd design micro-services responsible for a set of tasks revolving around a core functionality they're executing. (If I understood the stuff I read correctly).

So finally the question that's been burning on my mind:

*"How can I determine the correct scope for my microservice without having too many functionalities or turning it into a nano-service?"*

Let me pitch an example where I run into this issue with scoping:

I have a microservice consisting out of

1. Front-end (Stateless)
2. my 2 functions (Stateless)
3. Database (Stateful)

A user can either use the service directly through the front-end, or call it through an API which routes the request to either of my 2 functions.

I know my database should be separated from the other two due to it being a Stateful service, but it's point 1 and 2 I am concerned about. I have two core functionalities: Providing the graphical interface for the service and handling and processing the request for the service. Based on this I have separated these two into seperate microservices, but somehow I feel like my microservices have become nanoservices.

Because of this, I want to merge 1 and 2 into one microservice, but I am worried that I am designing a microservice equivalent to a web application.

Any help or input would very much be appreciated, many thanks.

*PS: I still have the books "Building Microservices" and "Microservices: Flexible Software Architecture" on the way.*

Comment: First of all I'd like to throw in this blog entry: https://aadrake.com/posts/2017-05-20-enough-with-the-microservices.html (it in turn refers to some nice articles). So I'd like to start with asking the question, why is the microservice architecture an inherent solution to your task?

Comment: Thank you for the blog robzor, I could go for the simple answer "because my superiors said so", but as anyone should know, never take anything at face value. I've done a little bit of digging and testing for monolithic vs microservices as our solution and microservices is better suited. Key roles for us are the availability of the service, response time with heavy user load. Adding new services without having to retest our already live platform. also the possibility to remove existing services after a roll-out phase. And some of the services might run heavier tasks than others.

Comment: How large is your company (number of employees, revenue)?

Comment: MS are built around business capabilities and people business skills.  Not around application procedures. Small business units managed by small teams. You might find interesting this [post](https://builttoadapt.io/whats-your-decomposition-strategy-e19b8e72ac8f). Or this [picture](https://www.instagram.com/p/BVVP61JlV04/). Special attention to the 3st point.